# WPF PreviewMouseRightButtonDown vs. MouseRightButtonDown events

Tags: wpf, mouseevent

When we are supposed to use the `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` event instead of `MouseRightButtonDown` while handling mouse right button events?

Please elaborate the ease of use.

Comment: you should understand bubbling and tunneling events in wpf to understand this. There are many article on this like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *real* difference between handling the `PreviewMouseRightButtonDown` and `MouseRightButtonDown` events except the timing of when each are called. Tunneling (`Preview...`) events are always called before the corresponding Bubbling events.

However @nit is correct... there is much written information relating to this online and so it is not worth writing again about that here. Please read the WPF Input Events section of the [Routed Events Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#how_event_processing_works) page on MSDN for further information.

Answer (score 1):

Preview Events are Tunneling events i.e they tunnel through parent to the origin child (where event has actually occured). While the other one are Bubbling events i.e they bubble from origin child to parent.

you should understand bubbling and tunneling events in wpf to understand this. There are many article on this like 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/464926/To-bubble-or-tunnel-basic-WPF-events